# Rx sequence of actions with Redux Observable

Tags: rxjs6, redux-observable

These epics are triggered by the user typing into a field.
The SET_TODO triggers a message saying that the user is typing.
Then if the typing stops for one second the message is that the user is not typing and then two seconds later the message is an empty string.

A couple of questions,

One: Is there a way to do this with one self contained epic?

Two: I used dummy actions (ones that are not in the Redux reducer), is this a bad hack?

cheers

```
import { concatMap, debounce, delay, mapTo } from 'rxjs/operators'
import { combineEpics, ofType } from 'redux-observable'
import { of, timer } from 'rxjs'

const enteringTextEpic = action$ =>
  action$.pipe(
    ofType('SET_TODO'),
    delay(200),
    concatMap(action =>
      of(
        { type: 'SET_MESSAGE', text: 'You are entering text' },
        { type: 'NOT' }
      )
    )
  )

const notEnteringTextEpic = action$ =>
  action$.pipe(
    ofType('NOT'),
    debounce(() => timer(1000)),
    concatMap(action =>
      of(
        { type: 'SET_MESSAGE', text: 'Now you are not entering text' },
        { type: 'FINISHED' }
      )
    )
  )
/**The actions NOT and FINISHED are dummy actions and are not in the reducer */
const finishedEnteringTextEpic = action$ =>
  action$.pipe(
    ofType('FINISHED'),
    debounce(() => timer(2000)),
    mapTo({ type: 'SET_MESSAGE', text: '' })
  )

const epica = combineEpics(
  enteringTextEpic,
  finishedEnteringTextEpic,
  notEnteringTextEpic
)

export default epica
```